# foreach execution: cannot allocate memory, while RAM still available

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, out-of-memory, doparallel

Before my last R update a couple of weeks ago (I am using now 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)), I was running the following code in parallel on my 19 cores (I have a Windows machine with a total of 24 virtual cores and a shared memory of 128 GB of RAM)

```
nport.total.all <- c(seq(10,100,10),seq(200,1000,100))

n.portfolios <- length(nport.total.all) 

nsim <- 100000 

ncores <- length(nport.total.all)
nruns <- 20 
data.VaR.L <- matrix(data = 0,nrow = nruns, ncol = ncores)
data.VaR.E.L.Y <- matrix(data = 0,nrow = nruns, ncol = ncores)
data.VaR.Analytical <- matrix(data = 0,nrow = nruns, ncol = ncores)


library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
library(iterators)

cl <- makePSOCKcluster(names = ncores)
registerDoParallel(cl)
getDoParWorkers()

start_time <- Sys.time()

paralleltest <- foreach(core = 1:ncores) %dopar% {
  
  nport.total <- nport.total.all[core] 
  
  alpha.LGD <- 2 
  beta.LGD <- 3 
  E.LGD  <- (alpha.LGD / (alpha.LGD + beta.LGD)) 
  Var.LGD <- (alpha.LGD * beta.LGD) / ( (alpha.LGD+beta.LGD)^2 *(alpha.LGD + beta.LGD + 1) ) 
  EAD <- rep(x = 1000, times = nport.total) 
  w.i <- EAD/sum(EAD) 
  min.PD <- 0.0005
  max.PD <- 0.018
  mean.PD <- (min.PD + max.PD) / 2 
  PD <- rep(x = mean.PD, times = nport.total)
  c  <- qnorm(PD) 
  Rho.PD <- 0.12 * ( (1-exp(-50*PD)) / (1-exp(-50)) ) + 0.24 * ( 1 - ( (1-exp(-50*PD)) / (1-exp(-50)) ) )
  alpha <- 0.999 
  
  for (run in 1:nruns) { 
    
    # /!\ EMPIRICAL PART /!\ DISTRIBUTION OF L
    
    Y              <- matrix(data = rnorm(nsim), nrow = nport.total, ncol = nsim, byrow = TRUE)  
    Z.Default      <- matrix(data = rnorm(nsim * nport.total), nrow = nport.total, ncol = nsim, byrow = FALSE) 
    LGD.Basel      <- matrix(data = rbeta(n = (nsim * nport.total), shape1 = alpha.LGD, shape2 = beta.LGD, ncp = 0), nrow = nport.total, ncol = nsim) 
    
    X.Default <- sqrt(Rho.PD) * Y + sqrt(1 - (Rho.PD)) * Z.Default 
    
    rm(Z.Default)
    gc()
    
    Default <- 1 * (X.Default < c) 
    
    
    Basel.Rel.Loss <- w.i * LGD.Basel * Default 
    Basel.Port.Rel.Loss <- apply(Basel.Rel.Loss, 2, sum) 
    
    Ecdf.Basel.Port.Rel.Loss <- ecdf(Basel.Port.Rel.Loss)
    VaR.Rel.Port.Basel <- as.numeric(quantile(x = Ecdf.Basel.Port.Rel.Loss, prob = alpha))
    
    rm(Default,Basel.Rel.Loss,LGD.Basel)
    gc()
    
    ##########################################################################################################################################################################
    
    # /!\ EMPIRICAL PART /!\ DISTRIBUTION OF E[L|Y]
    
    PD.Conditional <- pnorm( (qnorm(PD) - sqrt(Rho.PD) * Y) / sqrt(1-Rho.PD) ) 
    
    
    Basel.E.cond.portfolio.loss.i <- w.i * E.LGD * PD.Conditional 
    Basel.E.cond.portfolio.loss <- apply(Basel.E.cond.portfolio.loss.i, 2, sum) 
    
    Ecdf.Basel.E.cond.portfolio.loss <- ecdf(Basel.E.cond.portfolio.loss)
    VaR.Basel.E.cond.portfolio.loss <- as.numeric(quantile(x = Ecdf.Basel.E.cond.portfolio.loss, prob = alpha))
    
    rm(PD.Conditional,Basel.E.cond.portfolio.loss.i)
    gc()
    
    ##########################################################################################################################################################################
    
    # /!\ ANALYTICAL FORMULAS /!\
    
    VaR.Ana.Quantile.Basel_i <- w.i * E.LGD * pnorm((qnorm(PD)-sqrt(Rho.PD)*qnorm(1-alpha)) / sqrt(1-Rho.PD)) 
    VaR.Ana.Quantile.Basel <- sum(VaR.Ana.Quantile.Basel_i) 
    
    ##########################################################################################################################################################################
    
    # SAVE THE GENERATED VAR
    
    data.VaR.L[run,core] <- VaR.Rel.Port.Basel
    data.VaR.E.L.Y[run,core] <- VaR.Basel.E.cond.portfolio.loss
    data.VaR.Analytical[run,core] <- VaR.Ana.Quantile.Basel
    
    rm(Y)
    gc()
    
  }
  
  return(list(data.VaR.L,data.VaR.E.L.Y,data.VaR.Analytical)) 
  
}

end_time <- Sys.time() 
time.sim <- end_time - start_time

stopCluster(cl)
```

The *parallelisation strategy* is the following:

- Ask for 19 cores.
- On each of these 19 cores run a number of sequential operations. The size of these sequential operations is controlled by the variable **nsim** (essentially, the number of Monte Carlo Simulations to generate a distribution).

Nonetheless, by design, some cores will have to work with bigger matrices than others (due to different values of the **nport.total** impacting each core). The latter has never truly been a problem in earlier simulations, it just means that to "complete itself" the overall process will have to wait for the "last cores".

Until my last R update, I was able to increase/ decrease the **nsim** value, thanks to my RAM availability. However, I am currently unable to increase **nsim** without having one of the following error messages (depending on the **nsim** I introduce):

```
Error in { : task 17 failed - "cannot allocate vector of size 610.4 Mb"
```

I am struggling to understand what is going on/ what may have changed under the hood of R... When I check my computer resources usage thanks to Task Manager, I still have a lot of available RAM:

[image]

Intuitively, it is either that

1. R is no more allowed/ able to access the total RAM.
2. Each single CPU I parallelise on, is not allowed to access the entire RAM (hence there is a problem of CPUs not being able to share the entire RAM).

Anyone has had a similar problem?

Comment: Check your memory composition, it is a bar below your memory usage timeline.

I once had a similiar problem. The memory usage is slightly misleading. It sometimes does not account for reserved memory of an Application. Try to perform your calculation an watch the bar.  You might find that there is suddenly a new category hogging all the ram.  These are the R-Subprocesses reserving memory, but not using it. Therefore your Ram might be more under stress than you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify the R version you're running is 64 bit.  If it isn't, RAM allocation is limited to 4Gb if I remember right. In 64 bit R allocation is limited by memory available.

In RStudio:
Tools > Global Options > General > R version

I've had issues in the past with my machine (24 cores, 128 Gb RAM, 64bit) defaulting to 32 bit R for an unknown reason at seemingly random times.  In Global Options I had to manually change the R version to 64 bit to assure it stopped happening.